# v-model isn't recognized when used within a v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am trying to use the `TextField` component multiple times to create a form for the user to see/update his personal information (last name, first name...)

In order to not repeat myself I used `v-for` like so:

```
<TextField v-for="item in items" v-model="item.value" :text="item.text" :key="item.id" />
```

And my data look like this:

```
data: () => ({
   items: [
       {id: "first_name", text: "First Name", value: ""},
       {id: "last_name", text: "Last Name", value: ""},
   ]
})
```

However, whenever I type anything in one of those `TextField` the data isn't updated and the value stays as an empty string...

If I write my `TextField` like so:

```
<TextField v-model="first_name" text="First Name" />
<TextField v-model="last_name" text="Last Name" />
```

And my data like so:

```
data: () => ({
   last_name: "",
   first_name: "",
})
```

Then is does work...

As you can imagine, I have more than two fields and I need to be able to use the `v-for` loop.

NOTE: It used to work fine with Nativescript 6, but I had to change everything to Nativescript 7 because the app crashed since the latest version of iOS (14).

Comment: maybe this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60771140/7908390

Comment: This should work fine. https://jsfiddle.net/j1m5ognr/

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that you have a `v-model` and a `:text` attribute. You only need the `v-model`.  Perhaps you intended to use `:hint="item.text"` instead.